# Firestore - After orderby geoHash not able to sort documents based on another field

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geohashing, geofirestore

Example: Get top rated restaurants around me based on rating count

(Assume 10k restaurants around the area, so have to use limit)

My Query in Java:

```
ref.orderBy("geoHash")
     .orderBy("count", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
     .startAt(startHash)
     .endAt(endHash)
     .limit(limit)
```

But it doesn't works as expected even for a single GeoQueryBound.

Sample Document :

```
item1 : {
geoHash : tsp1
count : 100
}
item2 : {
geoHash : tsp1
count : 200
}
item3 : {
geoHash : tsp2 
count : 300
}
```

Now if we run the above query with geo bounds as tsp0 - tsp3 with limit as 2

Expected Results : [item3, item2]

Actual Results : [item2, item1]

Is this a limitation in firestore? Is there any workaround for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query first orders on `geoHash` and only then orders on `count`, so the count only affects the results for documents where the geohash is the same. Since `item1` and `item2` have the lowest geohash values, they occur first in the index and are correctly returned.

There is no effective way to do this query on the database, unless you find a way to merge the count into the geohash values in a way to puts them in the order you want in the index. While this *may* be possible, the more likely workaround is to only filter on geohash and then get the top results by count in your application code.